Appsettings from sub-folder
I would like to load three different appsettings.

appsettings.json
appsettings.A.json
other/appsettings.A.json

such that the user can put his appsettings.A.json into a subfolder, not interfering with deplyoments. However, the appsettings.A.json within the other folder doesn't get loaded. I tried a full-path, relative-path and now with the PhysicalFileProvider. However, it always uses the value from the appsettings.A.json. If I delete the appsettings.A.json it uses the fallback value from the default appsettings.json.
IHostBuilder builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().UseEnvironment("A");

builder.ConfigureHostConfiguration(config =>
{
    var userConfigProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "other"));

    config
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.A.json", false, true)
        .AddJsonFile(userConfigProvider, "appsettings.A.json", false, true);
});

builder.ConfigureServices((host, services) => services.Configure<Config>(host.Configuration));

IHost host = builder.Build();

Console.WriteLine(host.Services.GetService<IOptions<Config>>()!.Value.File);

Console.ReadLine();

What am I missing here? Also, the file does exist and I did perform a sanity check ofc.

You need ConfigureAppConfiguration instead of ConfigureHostConfiguration.
From the documentation:

The results will be available at Configuration for subsequent operations, as well as in Services.


That did the trick - thank you very much
